# Kendo grid binding with code-first model

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Why when my entities contain non-empty ICollection properties kendo grid not displays data? This occurs when I using code-first models with foreign key relations - parent entities that have childs made grid not display data and viсe versa: childs that have non-empty parents mades grid not work properly.Here is line of code that returns data from controller:

```
 return Json(context.SomeDBSet.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

here are entities:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    .....
    public virtual ICollection<ChildModel> ArticleContent { get; set; }

}

public class ChildModel
{
    ....
    public int? ParentModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
 return Json(context.SomeDBSet.Select( e => new { e.X, ....  e.Id}).ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

Dont include your 'ICollection' properties here.